# Compiling problems with wstring in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, wstring

I need to refactor a .dll for a Zinc based Flash application.

After copy&paste a class from the master to the branch, I'm getting some strange compiling errors:

```
GameInfo.h(15): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_wsVersion'
GameInfo.h(15): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
GameInfo.h(15): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

The addressed code:

```
// removed the comments
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>

class GameInfo {

public:

    UINT m_uiGameId;

    wstring m_wsVersion; // Line 15

    UINT m_uiCheckSum;

    wstring m_wsFilePath; // Same error report as on line 15

public:
    static BOOL createFromFile(wstring path, GameInfo &target); // error "error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'wstring'" thrown
};
```

I use Visual Studio 2010 and in the IDE itself everything is okay, no syntactical errors or something like that. And as said I did not touch the code, headers seem fine.

Has anyone a clue what about this error?

Comment: The C++ std::string functions are in their own header file <string>. <string.h> is the C header file, so change the #included file above to <string>

Comment: `wstring` is evil, twisted creature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the string header, and qualifying the namespace:

```
#include <string>

class GameInfo {
   ....  
   std::wstring m_wsVersion;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`#include <string>` is the right standard include in C++ for string classes and use `std::wstring`.

I strongly recommend AGAINST using a `using namespace std;` inside one of your headers, as you would force anybody using the header to pull in the std stuff into the global namespace.